# How to not render part of Component's children at first mount in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, components, focus, render

I have a dialog and in it an input which I want to be focused right when the dialog opens.

Since the dialog is made of other components inside it, the focus im trying to do doesn't appear
(apparently falls somewhere between the renders).

So a possible solution I came up with is to render all the dialog first except the DialogContent and its children and then render them.

I do that by initialize a boolean in the state of the class,
and in compenentDidMount function change its value.

Then do conditional rendering by this boolean.
like this:

`this.state = { renderedOnce: false }`

`componentDidMount() { this.setState({ renderedOnce: true})`

`renderedOnce && <DialogContent> {children} </DialogContent>`

It works and the input gets focused, but seems a bit messy.
Anyone has another way to solve this or knows if this one is best practice ?

(I read something about the existing of isMounted property of a class but I think that's an anti pattern).

Comment: Did you try using the `autoFocus` property? Sample: `<input type="email" autoFocus/>`. Notice the uppercase `F`. This is a React property that calls `focus()` on your input when it is mounted.

Comment: yes, but since it is wrapped with other components in the middle it loses its focus.
In general i would like an answer about the render of children after first mount anyway :)